# Cordova hello world app

Tags: android, cordova

I wanted to create an cordova hello world application but when i run `cordova run android` it throws me this error:

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
[Android SDK Platform 24].
Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

I saw that I had to implement the licenses in this HelloWorld application, but with no result!

This is what I also tried the root folder of this project:

```
mkdir "$ANDROID_SDK/licenses""|| true

echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter extra-android-support | grep 'package installed'
```

Also tried to find the ANDROID_HOME folder but I don't have AppData folder in my `User\Name\` which I think is pretty weird

Comment: as the error clearly states you have to first install the missing components using android SDK manager and then try to build the app

Comment: **AppData** is normally hidden form please enable to show hidden file and folder then try to search **AppData**